# PHP fwrite() function

Tags: php

I am new to programming and i was trying to write a PHP code that could.

1)Create a new file.

2)Add content from two files into that file.

Here is an example of what i am trying to do.

1)I have two files **one.txt** and **two.txt**.

2)Content of these two file is as follows.

one.txt=`abc123`

two.txt=`def456`

3)I want the following result in **result.txt**.

```
 abc123

 this is the result file.

 def456
```

I have tried doing it alot of different ways that i knew but could not make it work.
I am a beginner so having trouble getting started.
Thanks.

Comment: where exactly do you run into problems ? Can you read the content of existing files ? Can you create new file ?

Comment: [Here's all you need.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php) ;)

Comment: i can create **result.txt**(**result.txt** is not present before script is executed.)
i can not get content out of **one.txt** or **two.txt**

Answer (score 4):

If your target is **only to wrap the result file** just use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_content) and  [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents).

```
$content_one = file_get_contents("one.txt");
$content_res = file_get_contents("result.txt");
$content_two = file_get_contents("two.txt");
file_put_contents("result.txt", "$content_one\n$content_res\n$content_two");
```